# A gem cancan access denied mainController # dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localhost, cancancan

I'm following the onebitcode tutorial but I can not implement this gem, I updated the database, I uploaded the seeds, I restarted the server, but nothing worked, if I comment the gem in GemFile, it works again, but without the cancancan ... The error pops up in the browser, but I can not figure out how to resolve it.

```
#Error
```

> CanCan::AccessDenied in RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard
>
> You are not authorized to access this page.
>
> Extracted source (around line #217):

```
    if cannot?(action, subject, *args)
        message ||= unauthorized_message(action, subject)
        raise AccessDenied.new(message, action, subject)
      end
      subject
     end


#Ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

 
  end
end

#rails_admin.rb
RailsAdmin.config do |config|

  ## == Devise ==
    config.authenticate_with do
       warden.authenticate! scope: :user
    end
    config.current_user_method(&:current_user)

##== Cancancan ==
   config.authorize_with :cancan

  config.actions do
    dashboard                     # mandatory
    index                         # mandatory
    new
    export
    bulk_delete
    show
    edit
    delete
    show_in_app

  end
end

#gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancancan'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'byebug'
end
group :development do
 gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end

#routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/', as: 'rails_admin'
  resources :group_users
  resources :groups
  resources :users
  resources :company_sectors
  resources :sectors
  resources :companies

end

#seed.rb
#users
User.create name: 'Jose', kind: :user, email: 'user@teste.com', password: 123456
User.create name: 'Marcos', kind: :manager, email: 'manager@teste.com', password: 123456

#grupo
Group.create name: 'Grupo teste 1'
Group.create name: 'Grupo teste 2'

#Setor
Sector.create name: 'Grupo 1'
Sector.create name: 'Grupo 2'

#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  belongs_to :company_sector
  enum kind: [:user, :manager]
end

#users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:company_sector_id, :kind, :name)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by swapping the gems in Gemfile.

```
gem 'devise', '~> 4.3'

gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.15.0'
```

My problem was with the versions, I've specified the two, and now it's working.

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem:

```
#Ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
        can :dashboard, :all
        can :access, :rails_admin
        can :read, :dashboard
       #to allow access, you have to put this.
  end
end
```

Comment: Try adding some details/explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass `can :manage, :all` and make the condition true to access the pages.

Try below code:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

    def initialize(user)
      user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
      if user.email == "user@teste.com" # you can add any condition
        can :manage, :all
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: def initialize(user)
      user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
      if user.kind== :manage # you can add any condition
        can :manage, :all
      else
        can :read, :all
      end
    end

Comment: Because I have this kind in my user and I wanted to filter things by his kind. And this does not work, goes back to the error I had described before.

Comment: whats the value in `user.kind` ?

Comment: check Is `user.kind` is `symbol` ?

Comment: @ElisBresciani vote and accept my answer if it works for you. Thanks

Comment: No, I was wrong, sorry, I do not want to test if it's a symbol, I want to do something like that.

Comment: class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

    def initialize(user)
      user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
      if user.kind == 'manager' # you can add any condition
        can :manage, :all
      else
        can :read, :all

      end
    end
end

Comment: check your condition properly, if its true then only you can access the page

Comment: what happen if you add `can :manage, :all` in else part? Are you able to access page?

Comment: its clear that your `if` condition not works properly

Comment: add `gem 'pry'` in Gemfile and run `bundle`. Its used for debugging. Then add `binding.pry` before if condition...you can check the condition in your terminal then..test it

Comment: Okay, I debugged and now it's saying that: '' ' <class: Ability> ': uninitialized constant Ability :: CanCan (NameError) "

Comment: you have to place `binding.pry` before `if ` statement. Send me the code

Comment: def initialize(user)
    binding.pry
    user ||= User.new 
    if user.kind == 'manager' then
        can :manage, :all

    else
        can :read, :all



    end

Comment: Correct. Is your console stop in terminal

Comment: Using if user.manager? it does not want to work. He said he expected ":" in a completely random place. And if he put it on, he said that the placement was wrong.

Comment: Try some different code like user.kind=='manager' or user.kind== :manager

Comment: Whats the value of user.kind in your terminal??

Comment: The value is user